# Entity Query for dynamic properties

Tags: google-app-engine, properties, entity, datastore

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to persist and query data from a datastore (specifically Google App Engine).

The entity will store useful information entered by the user. My goal is to create a property for each individual word a user enters. My current approach involves users entering words they wish to store in a single text box, separated by a space. When the user hits "Submit", I then parse the string and store each word in a single array. (so the sentence "I will be home soon" becomes [I, will, be, home, soon] (without commas).

The problem is, I don't know what words will be entered, and I also don't know how many words there will be. Assuming that I can correctly loop through my array and pluck out each word one at a time and store it as a property, can I retrieve all of the properties of that particular entity simultaneously?

Thank you for your suggestions!
-Dan

Comment: This sounds like what the Search API was designed for.  Have you looked into that?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for Expando.